# Change Label Value on button click in Xamarin MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing an issue in Xamarin forms Mvvm. I have 2 different layouts say Layout1 and Layout2 which are bounded with a common ViewModel. Layout1 contains multiple Labels which I'm generating dynamically using for loop in xaml.cs file and bind each Label'sTextProperty using SetBinding. Layout2 contain a button.

***Now I want to change Text of a particular Label when button clicked.***

Layout1.xaml

```
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="Layout1">

<StackLayout x:Name="ParentStack">

 // dynamic Labels to be added here..

</StackLayout>           
</StackLayout>
```

Layout1.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class Layout1: StackLayout
{
    public Label dummyLabel;
    public Layout1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
         dummyLabel= new Label
         {
           Text = " ",  
         };
         dummyLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty,"PhaseValue");
         parentRowCells.Children.Add(dummyLabel);
         var tapGestureRecognizer_1 = new TapGestureRecognizer();                
            tapGestureRecognizer_1.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty,"LabelClicked");
            tapGestureRecognizer_1.CommandParameter = dummyLabel;
            dummyLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer_1);
             }

          }

        }
```

Layout2.Xaml

```
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 x:Class="Layout2">

<StackLayout x:Name="ParentStack">
<Button Command={Binding ButtonClickedCommand} Text="Click Me"  />
</StackLayout>           

</StackLayout>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
 class ViewModel
{

    public Label label = new Label();
    public string textstring = "new text string";
    ICommand _labelClicked;
    public ICommand LabelClicked
    {
        get
        {
            this._labelClicked= this._labelClicked?? new Command(s =>
            {

                label = s as Label;
             label.Text = "new text"; //this change the text of particular              label when clicked but i need it from button clicked event from another layout.
                // here I'm getting the instance of label which i clicked on label.

            });

            return this._labelClicked;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand{ protected set; get; }



    public ViewModel()
    {

        this.ButtonClickCommand = new Command<Button>((key) =>
        {

        //here I want to change the value of label when button command is clicked.  
         aa.Text = "this is not changing the text";
        });

    }



}
```

Any help in this or do I need to follow some other pattern..??

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to add each `Label` that you add to a `List<Label>` somewhere that you can access from both layouts... your View Model would seem like the logical place. Then when you click your button, you can find the particular `Label` whose text you want to change and change it. You will likely then have to reload your list.

However I think that a better way would be to use a `ListView` instead of a `StackLayout`. Then you can have an `ItemTemplate` for the `ListView` that includes one Label. You can then set up an `ObservableCollection<T>` of objects to use as the `ListView.ItemsSource`. You would want to make some custom object that has a Text property, or whatever you want to call the property that will hold the text for the Labels. It is better to use an object for the `T` in `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than using `ObservableCollection<string>` because changes to a string type will not be reflected in the `ListView` item, but changes to a property of an object (assuming of course that you make it a Bindable Property) will be reflected in those controls that are bound to that property. So in a nutshell, something like (in your ViewModel):

```
// Class level variable
ObservableCollection<CustomType> dummyLabelContents;

// then either in the ViewModel constructor or somewhere else:
dummyLabelContents = new ObservableCollection<CustomType>();

CustomType dummyText;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dummyText = new CustomType
    {
        Text = " ",  
    };
}
dummyLabelContents.Add(dummyText);
```

And your `CustomType` would just be a simple class with only a `BindableProperty` called `Text`.

Set up like this, you can assign your `ListView.ItemsSource` to be the `dummyLabelContents` `ObservableCollection` and then whenever you add an item to the `ObservableCollection`, the ListView will update automatically. Also, since using a custom type with a bindable text property in the `ObservableCollection`, when that text property is changed the item in the `ListView` should also update accordingly.